# gif is not shown in ie11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a class with a gif, it works fine in Chrome, but the gif is not shown in IE11.

The code is quite simple, just a div, with a class which contains the gif image

```css
<style>
    .velo {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        opacity: 0.3;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99999999;
    }
    .preloader {
        background: url(myroute/preloader.gif) no-repeat center;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 999999999999;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1\">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="velo">
        <div class="preloader">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: what does this do in the meta tag? ;=""
also, use quotes around the url: url('myroute/preloader.gif')

Comment: Any message on browser's console?

Comment: is your route to the gif valid?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Meta tag was a mistake coping my code. There is no message on console, and the route is valid, it works in chrome.

Comment: I also add quotes, but I can't see the gif anyway